# LinkedIn / OAuth question

Tags: safecracker, twitter, social, oauth

I have a client that has an (I think) odd request: I know there are modules like Social Login Pro that connect someone's Facebook / LinkedIn to a member account, but what my client wants to do is:

Allow users to submit "tips". To submit a tip, you don't need to register, you just enter your tip, after which you're prompted to either "enter your personal information yourself" or "use your linkedin profile". This should be stored with the entry, not in a member-profile, and people should be allowed to submit multiple tips.

How would this even work OAuth-wise? Are you allowed to request someone's personal info again?

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With Social Login Pro, you can let user add connection to LinkedIn profile after he's already registered and logged in to your system.

If that is what you're asking, as the question is not too clear :)